# PHP MySQL find smallest missing number in column

Tags: php, mysql, int

I need to read a column with INT `Order` in MySQL and get from the column the lower number missing:

```
+--------+---------+
| ID     | Order   |
+--------+---------+
| 1      | 1       |
| 3      | 5       |
| 4      | 3       |
| 5      | 4       |
| 6      | 2       |
| 7      | 6       |
| 8      | 11      |
+--------+---------+
```

The result I need is the number 7, as 1 through 6 exist and other missing numbers are greater than 7.

```
$stmtpre    =   "SELECT Order FROM tabla ORDER BY Order DESC";
$data       =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDquery($stmtpre);
        $count      =   0;
        while ($row =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
            $count++;
            if($row['Order']!==$count){
                $result= $count; #store first lower get
                break;
            }
        }
return $result;
```

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word - and why not number 0?

Comment: thank order is a example, only numbers > 0. i have put a new Answer dinamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `Order` column is indexed, you could get the first missing number with SQL, without reading the complete table using an excluding LEFT JOIN:

```sql
SELECT t1.`Order` + 1 AS firstMissingOrder
FROM tabla t1
LEFT JOIN tabla t2 ON t2.`Order` = t1.`Order` + 1
WHERE t2.`Order` IS NULL
  AND t1.`Order` <> (SELECT MAX(`Order`) FROM tabla)
ORDER BY t1.`Order`
LIMIT 1
```

or (maybe more intuitive)

```sql
SELECT t1.`Order` + 1 AS firstMissingOrder
FROM tabla t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tabla t2
    WHERE t2.`Order` = t1.`Order` + 1
) 
    AND t1.`Order` <> (SELECT MAX(`Order`) FROM tabla)
ORDER BY t1.`Order`
LIMIT 1
```

The second query will be converted by MySQL to the first one. So they are practicaly equal.

**Update**

Strawberry mentioned a good point: The first missing number might be `1`, which is not covered in my query. But i wasn't able to find a solution, which is both - elegant and fast.

We could go the opposite way and search for the first number after a gap. But would need to join the table again to find the last existing number before that gap.

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(t3.`Order`) + 1, 1) AS firstMissingOrder
FROM tabla t1
LEFT JOIN tabla t2 ON t2.`Order` = t1.`Order` - 1
LEFT JOIN tabla t3 ON t3.`Order` < t1.`Order`
WHERE t1.`Order` <> 1
  AND t2.`Order` IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.`Order`
ORDER BY t1.`Order`
LIMIT 1
```

MySQL (in my case MariaDB 10.0.19) is not able to optimize that query properly. It takes about one second on an indexed (PK) 1M row table, even though the first missing number is 9. I would expect the server to stop searching after `t1.Order=10`, but it seams not to do that.

Another way, which is fast but looks ugly (IMHO), is to use the original query in a subselect only if `Order=1` exists. Otherwise return `1`.

```sql
SELECT CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tabla WHERE `Order` = 1) THEN 1
    ELSE (
        SELECT t1.`Order` + 1 AS firstMissingOrder
        FROM tabla t1   
        LEFT JOIN tabla t2 ON t2.`Order` = t1.`Order` + 1
        WHERE t2.`Order` IS NULL
          AND t1.`Order` <> (SELECT MAX(`Order`) FROM tabla)
        ORDER BY t1.`Order`
        LIMIT 1
    )
END AS firstMissingOrder
```

Or Using `UNION`

```sql
SELECT 1 AS firstMissingOrder FROM (SELECT 1) dummy WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tabla WHERE `Order` = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT firstMissingOrder FROM (
    SELECT t1.`Order` + 1 AS firstMissingOrder
    FROM tabla t1
    LEFT JOIN tabla t2 ON t2.`Order` = t1.`Order` + 1
    WHERE t2.`Order` IS NULL
      AND t1.`Order` <> (SELECT MAX(`Order`) FROM tabla)
    ORDER BY t1.`Order`
    LIMIT 1
) sub
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I don't know if it works but I knew there had to be query to do it.

Comment: Test it, then you will know :-)

Comment: t2 where do you get? it uses two tables. ??

Comment: You can use the same table multiple times in one query (except of temporary tables) and treat them like two separate, equal tables. But you need to give them distict aliases. `t1` and `t2` are aliases for the same table (`tabla`).

Comment: I think we have to allow for the possibility that the missing value might be the first one.

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for good point. But now the solution isn't that cute :-)

Comment: Perhaps the OP should have picked *my* solution ;-)

Comment: Your 3rd solution does seem blisteringly fast!

Comment: @Strawberry, not sure which one you do mean. But the last two queries execute in "no time" if the first missing number is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

Might be the long way around, but here's one way:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $orders[] = $row['Order'];
}

$result = min(array_diff(range(min($orders), max($orders)), $orders));
```

- Create a range from the minimum order found to the maximum order found
- Calculate the difference with the found orders to get missing orders
- Find the lowest order number from the missing

This assumes that you want to use the lowest and highest numbers returned from the query as the range.  If you want to always start at 1 use 1 instead of `min($orders)`.

Also, as *Strawberry* points out, `Order` is a reserved word in MySQL so consider changing it or delimit it with back-ticks **SELECT `Order` FROM tabla**.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP side:

i work more around the solution:

Fisrt call Function:

```
$stmtpre    =   "SELECT Order FROM tabla ORDER BY Order ASC";
$data       =   $this   ->  DBMANAGER   ->  BDqueryFirstMissingINT($stmtpre, DATABASE);
echo    $data;
```

On second

```
function BDqueryFirstMissingINT($stmtpre,$dbUsing){
    $data       =   $this   ->  BDquery($stmtpre, $dbUsing); #run the query
    $count      =   0;
    while ($row =   mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        $count++;
        $value  =   (int)$row[0];
        if($value!==$count){
            $result = $count;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Thank for you help

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

```
SELECT x.my_order + 1 missing 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT my_order FROM my_table 
        UNION 
       SELECT 0
     ) x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.my_order = x.my_order + 1 
 WHERE y.my_order IS NULL 
 ORDER 
    BY missing 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That one works fine. But you are reading the entire table in the subselect. It takes more than 2 seconds on my 1M row test table.

Comment: Just tested it with `UNION ALL` and it "only" takes less than 0.4 seconds. This way it would be a good (readable) solution for smaller tables.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Your hardware's 10 x faster than mine :-(