# How to SELECT first available id with WHERE using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

There is a table `table` there is a column `column` and another column `userId`.
Table `table` can have any amount of rows with same userId. However, in collection of `SELECT column, userId FROM table` there should never be columns with duplicate (column,userId) rows.
The rows will be often created, read, updated, deleted and created. 
I want every userId have it's local `column` id, like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| column | userId |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      3 |      1 |
|      4 |      1 |
|      5 |      1 |
|    ... |    ... |
|      1 |      2 |
|      2 |      2 |
|      3 |      2 |
|      4 |      2 |
|      5 |      2 |
|    ... |    ... |
+--------+--------+
```

And when a row is deleted, I want to grab the first available column `column` id of some `userId`. I would:

```
SELECT AVAILABLE_ID(column)
 FROM table WHERE userId = 1 ORDER BY column ASC LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT FIRST_AVAILABLE_ID(column)
 FROM table WHERE userId = 1
```

So, if we saw this state of table `table`:

```
+--------+--------+
| column | userId |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      3 |      1 |
|      5 |      1 |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to receive:

```
+--------+
| column |
+--------+
|      4 |
+--------+
```

And if I am inserting the first row for some userId, I want the column to be:

```
+--------+
| column |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

And if there is no missing gaps in between, I want just to `SELECT` the next available `column`.
Also, the table `table` with be heavy with create, update, delete ops, so I want any solutions which would be fast with thousands or millions of rows.
I think this query is not optimised:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.column+1 AS Id
    FROM table t1
    WHERE userId = 1 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE userId = 1 AND t2.column = t1.column + 1 )
    UNION 
    SELECT 1 AS column
    WHERE userId = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t3 WHERE userId = 1 AND t3.column = 1)) ot
ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1
```

Now, to explain in more details why I need this:
The reason is purely cosmetic.
I am working on a strategy game where players can have troops. Troops can have two states: grouped or not grouped. If they are grouped, a few rows will have same group_id. I then SUM them all together into a single row and combine with other rows in a query result set, some of which can be grouped or not. If they are grouped, I want each players' group troops to have unique group_number's relative to player's other troops.
So I can show them like:

1-st army,

2-nd army,

3-rd army,

...

100-th army,

etcetera

That's is not critical to the app's functionality, but I found that having numbering system like this, the armies are more memorable and easy to identify, then, say, displaying some "random" long id

Comment: You may get a fast query that does the job you want, but, are you sure your business logic really needs this sort of functionality?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us why you really need to implement this.  It will be fairly complex and a lot of work to build and maintain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Oksy.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated to answer you.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268477/php-mysql-find-smallest-missing-number-in-column

Comment: @MoeEpo If Bill Karwin can't even give you a perfect solution, then I'm out.  If I were you, I'd try to shift some of this logic to the app side of things.  Database are great are storing and manipulating data, less so at implementing business logic.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Thanks! I will check this out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Alright,  but I don't think it's possible to implement any other way. I think I need to think about this more.

Comment: Right on...well you have Bill's answer below to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are good at tracking data that is present, but not as good at tracking data that is missing.

You can find a gap this way:

```
select t1.col+1 as avail_col
from mytable as t1
left outer join mytable as t2 
  on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.col+1 = t2.col
where t1.userid = 1234 /* whatever userid you search for */ 
  and t2.col is null
order by avail_col limit 1;
```

You need an index on (userid, col) to optimize this.

This solution is pretty simple, but it has a couple of flaws, that it doesn't work when you are creating the first row for a given userid (except if it returns no rows, you know that position 1 is availabe), and subsequently it will never tell you if position 1 is the first available gap.

Also, beware of [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Your query might find a gap, but before your code inserts a new row to use the gap, another concurrent request could be doing the same thing, find the same gap, and fill it. The only ways to prevent that are:

- Guarantee that no more than one request at a time is working on data for a given userid.
- Use a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to lock all the rows for a given userid as you SELECT for the gap.

It's not clear why you need to fill these gaps. In most cases when I see similar questions, the application needs to change its design to avoid the requirement to fill gaps.

---

You added detail to your question that you want to use this to assign names to armies:

> 1-st army, 2-nd army, 3-rd army, ...

You could consider creating another table "unused_army_names" or something. Fill it at the start of the game with 100 rows per user_id.

When a user creates an army, do a locking read to pick the first entry from that table, and delete it from the table as you insert it

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO armies (army_name, user_id)
SELECT @army_name := army_name, user_id
FROM unused_army_names 
WHERE user_id = 1234 
ORDER BY army_name LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

DELETE FROM unused_army_names 
WHERE user_id = 1234 AND army_name = @army_name;

COMMIT;
```

Because I use `FOR UPDATE`, this locks the rows I select as it reads them, so if another concurrent request tries the same thing, it'll stop and wait to acquire its own lock. Once my first transaction commits, it releases the lock and the other transaction goes. By that time, I have deleted army 4 from the unused army tables, and the other transaction will read the *next* available army name.

I use a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) to remember the army name so I can delete it. One could also do this in three steps: SELECT to get the army name, INSERT to the armies table, DELETE from the unused_army_names table.

By using a transaction to wrap these two changes (and assuming you use InnoDB which supports transactions), they are guaranteed to appear as an single atomic change to other clients. No one can see the data in a partially-completed state.

Then when an army is lost, put it back:

```
START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM armies 
WHERE user_id = 1234 AND army_name = ?;

INSERT INTO unused_army_names (army_name, user_id) VALUES (?, 1234);

COMMIT;
```

I'm assuming at this point in the code, you know which army is lost, and you can pass the army name as a parameter to both queries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. For reason, check my update.